# Flex Containers to Accommodate an Image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am doing a website, and would like a layout like a photo gallery. For this, I am using a flex container, and image inside each div. I have the code set up like this:

```
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
}

.flex-image {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 20px;
 font-size: auto;
 padding: 100px;
}

<div class="header"><h1>Gallery</h1></div>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-image" style = "background-image:url(Images/Sample1.jpg);">
<img url ("Images/Sample1.jpg")></div>
<div class="flex-image" style = "background-image:url(Images/Sample2.jpg);">
</div>
<div class="flex-image" style = "background-image:url(Images/Sample3.jpg);">
</div>
</div>
```

However, whenever I attempt to execute this code, I am presented with only the top right corners of the images. How might I solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain` on your `.flex-image` styles

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)